# tenserflowが開けません

Tags: tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

とAnacondaのPyhonコンソールに打ったら

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
　 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

と出てきます。どうしたらよいでしょうか。

Comment: 単純にtensorflowがインストールされていない、または仮想環境で読み取れないときに質問のエラーが出ます。pythonコンソールではなく通常のコンソールで`pip install tensorflow`を実行すると正しく動作するでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございました、できました。GPUバージョンだけをインストールしてました。丁寧に、ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

解決したようなのでコメントより転記します。

単純にtensorflowがインストールされていない、または仮想環境で読み取れないときに質問のエラーが出ます。
pytho‌​nコンソールではなく通常のコンソールで`p‌​ip install tensorflow`を実行すると正しく動作する可能性があります。